# SWIFTUI: app buttons logic - change label in specific scenario

Tags: if-statement, button, swiftui, label, logic

My app has a number of mainButton created by a single struct. The data is passed to these buttons from an array. Then I have a Submit button.

I am trying to have the Submit button to change label to a arrow up icon only when: a given instance of mainButton has been pressed once already and changed its color and size already (this works), and Submit was pressed once already. Now the Submit button's icon changes to a refresh symbol (arrow up), until a diffrent instance of mainButton has been pressed (and this new button in turn has changed the color and size already as expected).

Basically a button representing a value is selected(tapped) and then its content submitted by pressing the Submit button, and if you submit the same button again the submitter is a refresher (arrow up icon) rather than a submitter (Submit label) as you have submitted that given query before; hence if you want to submit the same value again, the button is submit button is labeled as a refresher. The code below should make this clearer.

I am new to Swift/SwiftUI and trying to do this in a simple way as I want to understand it fully. Hence, if possible, I would rather use if conditions and variables rather than advanced methods.

Here is a simplified version of my code with only place holders in it:

```
//
//  AddView.swift
//  WriteOn
//
//  Created by Maurizio Zappettini on 2/11/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct AddView: View {
    
    @State private var typeofMessageGeneric: String = ""
    @State private var lastButtonTapped: String = ""
    @State private var buttonCount: Int = 0
    
    let buttonData = [
        (mainButtonText: "A", mainButtonValue: "a"),
        (mainButtonText: "B", mainButtonValue: "b"),
        (mainButtonText: "C", mainButtonValue: "c"),
        (mainButtonText: "D", mainButtonValue: "d"),
    ]
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
      
        ZStack {  // Using ZStack for background gradient
            Rectangle()
                .frame(
                    minWidth: 0,
                    maxWidth: .infinity,
                    minHeight: 0,
                    maxHeight: .infinity,
                    alignment: .topLeading)
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
                .background(LinearGradient(colors: [.blue, .purple], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            
            
            VStack {  //Master VStack
                
                
                VStack { //Headline
                    
                    
                    
                    Text("Test View")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                    
                }
                
                
                GeometryReader { geometry in  // Debug alignment
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {  //TextBox
                        
                        
                        
                        Rectangle()
                         .fill(Color.cyan)
                         .cornerRadius(20)
                         .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.8, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                       
                        
                        
                         .overlay(
                                HStack(alignment: .top){
                                    VStack {
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                    ScrollView {
                                        VStack(alignment: .center) {
                                            
                                            Text("getResponsePlaceHolder")
                                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                                                .layoutPriority(2)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    VStack{
                                        
                                        ShareLink(item: "nothing"){
                                            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                                            
                                                .resizable()
                                                .scaledToFit()
                                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                    VStack{
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                    .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.6) // find way to make it refer to actual box and not whole screen
                    )
                        
                         .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                                
                            } //Vstack Top
                    
            }  //Geo Reader
                Spacer(minLength: 50
                )
                
              
                    ScrollView{
                        VStack { //Buttons
                            
                            ForEach(buttonData, id: \.mainButtonValue) { data in
                                
                                mainButton(typeofMessageGeneric: self.$typeofMessageGeneric, lastButtonTapped: self.$lastButtonTapped, buttonCount: self.$buttonCount, mainButtonText: data.mainButtonText, mainButtonValue: data.mainButtonValue)
                                
                                
                            }
                        } //Button Vstack end
                    }
                
          
               
                VStack{  //Footer
                    
               
                    
                   submitButton()

                     
                }
              
                }
            
        }
    }
    
    func submitButton() -> some View {
        
        return Button(action: getResponse) {
            if self.typeofMessageGeneric == self.lastButtonTapped && self.buttonCount == 0 {
                Text("Submit")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            } else {
                
                Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise.circle")
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            
            
        }
        
        
    }
        
       
        
        // Create main buttons
        
        struct mainButton: View {
            
            @Binding var typeofMessageGeneric: String // Bind the variable inside this struct with the same one inside the ContentView struct
            @Binding var lastButtonTapped: String // Not currently used -- implement later if needed
            @Binding var buttonCount:Int
            
            var mainButtonText:String
            var mainButtonValue:String
            
            
            var body: some View {
                Button(action: {
                    

                    self.typeofMessageGeneric =  mainButtonValue
                    self.lastButtonTapped = mainButtonValue
                    
                    buttonCount = 0
                    
                    if self.typeofMessageGeneric == mainButtonValue{
                        buttonCount = 1
                    } else {
                        buttonCount = 0
                    }
                    
                                        
                }) {
                    Text(mainButtonText)
                    Text(String(buttonCount)) // testing only
                }
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .background(self.mainButtonValue == self.typeofMessageGeneric ? Color.teal : Color.purple)
                
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .scaleEffect(self.mainButtonValue == self.typeofMessageGeneric ? 1.12 : 1)
                .animation(.easeOut, value: 2)
                
                
                
            }
        }
        
                   
        
        

    func getResponse() {
    }
    
}
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    





















struct AddView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddView()
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is a better explanation of what the app does and what I am trying to achieve in terms of button logic.

What's on the screen when you start the app:

- There is an empty text box.
- There are 4 buttons (it will be more)
- There is a Submit button at the bottom

What the app does:

- The 4 main buttons are 4 different prompts. Each prompt/button is composed of a label and an associated value.
- Tapping a button acts as a way to select that button's corresponding value.
- Tapping the submit button will submit the value of the last selected main buttons to an external API. The latter will return some specific data that is visualized in the text box above (this part I left out as it is unrelated to my button label problem).
- If the same prompt is submitted again the API will return different data (as there is a randomization mechanism). Hence, the user may want to submit again the same prompt they have submitted already.

How the buttons behave (practical example):

1- You tap button B

2- Button B changes the background color from purple to teal and becomes bigger.

3- You tap the "Submit" button.

4- The submit button changes its label from "Submit" to ARROW_UP.

5- The app submits value "b" to the API and this returns DATA_b_1.

6- DATA_b_1 is visualized in the text box.

7- Button B is still 'selected' (it is still teal and larger)

8- You tap ARROW_UP.

9- Value "b" is submitted again to the API and this now returns
DATA_b_2 (a different random instance of DATA_b).

10- DATA_b_2 is visualized in the text box.

11- You now tap button D.

12- Button D changes the background color from purple to teal and becomes bigger.

13- Button B reverts its color to purple and its size to smaller.

14- ARROW_UP button reverts its label to "Submit".

15- Back to point 3

Everything in the list above works as expected except the "Submit" to ARROW_UP and vice-versa label changes.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what you are trying to achieve, the. question is not very clear to me. What I got is:

1. Show the question and 4 possible answers to the user. Let the user select an answer. **Submit button: disabled**.
2. The user selects one answer; they can change their mind as much as they want until the answer is submitted. **Submit button: enabled**.
3. The user pressed "Submit": they can't press any other button, except for "Refresh". **Submit button: "arrow up"**.
4. The user pressed "Refresh": go back to 1.

If that's the case, you just need to track two things:

- what is the selected answer (when none is selected, nothing can be submitted)
- when the answer was submitted - then, the only option is to refresh the question

By the way, your variable `buttonCount` is pointless: if you have only one variable for the whole view, all buttons will show the same number.

With a good set of `if`s and `else`s, the "Submit" button can be disabled, enabled or show "arrow up", and perform the right action. Here's the code:

```
    
// Track which button was pressed - or none of them (starting case)
@State private var buttonPressed: String = ""

// Track if a choice was submitted - when submitted, the Submit button can only refresh
@State private var isWaitingToRefresh = false

// For testing only - tests the refresh
@State private var question = "0"

// (other code)

var body: some View {

// (other code)
                                        Text("getResponsePlaceHolder \(question)")
// (other code)

            ScrollView{
                VStack { //Buttons
                    
                    ForEach(buttonData, id: \.mainButtonValue) { data in
                        
                        // Call a function, no need for binding vars
                        mainButton(mainButtonText: data.mainButtonText,
                                   mainButtonValue: data.mainButtonValue)
                        
                    }
                } //Button Vstack end
            }
            
            submitButton()
        }
    }
}

func submitButton() -> some View {
    
    Button {
        
        // No action if no button was pressed
        guard !buttonPressed.isEmpty else { return }
        
        // Check if you need to refresh the question
        if isWaitingToRefresh {
            
            // If the view is waiting to refresh, then refresh the question
            refresh()
            isWaitingToRefresh = false
        } else {
            
            // If the view is not waiting to refresh, submit the user's choice
            isWaitingToRefresh = true
            getResponse()
        }
        
    } label: {
        if !isWaitingToRefresh {
            Text("Submit")
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
            
                // Gray-out the button if the user made no choice yet
                .background(buttonPressed.isEmpty ? Color.secondary :  Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(10)
        } else {
            
            Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise.circle")
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
    }
    
    // Disable the button if the user made no choice yet
    .disabled(buttonPressed.isEmpty)
}


// Create main buttons

// Call a function, no need for binding vars:
// you can use the same variables of the view
func mainButton(mainButtonText: String,
                mainButtonValue: String) -> some View {
    Button {
        
        // You just need to change the choice when a button is pressed,
        // let the Submit button do the rest
        buttonPressed =  mainButtonValue
        
    } label: {
        Text(mainButtonText)
        Text(String("same number for all buttons")) // testing only
    }
    .font(.system(size: 20))
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .padding()
    .background(mainButtonValue == buttonPressed ? Color.teal : Color.purple)
    
    .cornerRadius(10)
    .scaleEffect(mainButtonValue == buttonPressed ? 1.12 : 1)
    .animation(.easeOut, value: 2)
    
    // Do not let the user change the choice if it was already submitted
    .disabled(isWaitingToRefresh)
    
}

// Remember to reset the user's choice (buttonPressed = "")
func refresh() {
    buttonPressed = ""
    question = String(Int.random(in: 1...100))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am sorry my explanation was not very clear. I know what I want to achieve but it is very hard to verbalize it efficiently. I tried to break it down again and added it to my question above. In the meantime, I checked your code, but the logic above is still not what I am trying to achieve. The breakdown above should be clearer.